# Where to populate multiple dropdown lists

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to determine the correct approach to populating multiple dropdown lists on a view page of an .net MVC application, which is using angularJS.

In my app, designed as a silo-SLA app. I'm using the angular ngRoute module, and the $routeProvider to describe the multiple HTML pages for a single CSHTML page.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/club', { templateUrl: '/App/Club/Views/MCLView.html', controller: 'mclViewModel' });
        $routeProvider.when('/club/list', { templateUrl: '/App/Club/Views/MCLView.html', controller: 'mclViewModel' });
        $routeProvider.when('/club/show/:clubId', { templateUrl: '/App/Club/Views/ClubView.html', controller: 'clubViewModel' });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/club' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

My CSHTML page is basically empty except for the `<div ng-view></div>` tag.  The routed HTML pages get loaded into the ng-view div.

```
<div data-ng-app="club" id="club" data-ng-controller="rootViewModel">
    <h2>{{ pageHeading }}</h2>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div
```

Each html view page loaded into the ng-view has an associated viewmodel javascript controller.

I started out populating the first dropdown on the html page by using $http.get in the angular controller to get the list data (json) from a server call. Then do a JSON.parse on the result.data and populate the select list control that is defined in the html page.

```
$scope.refreshColorsDropdown = function () {

    var sel = document.getElementById('colorDropdown');
    var colors = JSON.parse($scope.mycolors);
    angular.forEach(colors, function(color) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = color.name;
        opt.value = color.hex;
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    });
}
```

I could continue this approach for each dropdown on my page, creating several server calls to populate all my dropdowns  ... but this seems tedious and code heavy.

Would a reasonable approach be to consider building one server calls that returns multiple collections, one for each dropdown, and then I'd parse those to populate all the dropdowns?

I'd like to pre-populate the lists on the server side C# code, however my cshtml files are empty except for the ng-view div, so there's no coding going on there.

So to my question ... if my HTML views contain all the html content, and the cshtml are empty ... what strategy should I be using to populate multiple html list controls from the server side?

Comment: Why do you use JS DOM manipulations to create angular lists? Why not to do it angular way via ng-repeat?

Comment: @Kindzoku ... that's a valid question. Answer is because I couldn't get the ng-repeat to work with my json response, so I defaulted to what I know. And also, I'm still learning the angular way. Its on my todo, to convert it to ng-repeat.

Comment: hurry up with your ToDo ;) Here is an example with async data. 2 ways to create DropDowns in angular. https://plnkr.co/edit/32Sl09mOtANf27z4azW8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MVC, you can make a ViewModel that contains all collections needed and return this collection to your Angular Controller.
 Your View Model would be something like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
public List<ColorModel> Colors{get;set;}
public List<FabircModel> Fabrics {get;set;}
}
```

In your MVC Controller:

```
MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel();
mvm.Colors = get colors here;
mvm.Fabrics = get fabrics here;

return Json(mvm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In your success object in Angular:

```
myservice.getData()
.success(function(data){
$scope.colors = data.Colors;
$scope.fabrics = data.Fabrics;
})
```

Hopefully, that helps or at least gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for that design idea approach. I can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the fact you are using angular the answer would be to populate a view model with what you need and razor the cshtml, because you are using angular...nothing changes....because you said SERVER-SIDE that is still the answer.

If you move this to the client an angular service that can cache the data is probably the most direct way.